# How to open new ViewController after click(touch) on ImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

I have TableViewController with a custom cells.

For **table** is responsible class:

```
@interface CustomTableViewController : UITableViewController
```

For **cells** is responsible class:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
```

The ImageView are located in cell of table.

How I can open new controller when I click(touch) at ImageView inside cells?

As it appears I must to use `UIViewController` near `UITableViewCell` that to open new viewController, is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this kind of stuff is handled inside `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. However the table view calls this method when the entire cell is tapped.

If you want to trigger the action only for the image, you might have to add `UITapGesture` to the image view. Do not forget that image views have `userInteractionEnabled` set to false by default. There are two ways to communicate the tap event to the view controller that i can think of right now. Either by delegation or closure. The latter one requires less code.

Comment: Could you share one example with `UITapGesture` and can I write code in `class(@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell)` for cell?

Comment: And how I can send to event ID of image?

Comment: You know the `NSIndexPath` of the cell, from this you can get the ID of image.

Comment: I format cells in class tableView, but events of cells there are in class any

Comment: I mean how I can get tag of image in: `[self.avatarView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture1];` - `- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{//HERE}`

Comment: i do not know what you want to put there but most likely that code doesn't belong to your view but your controller. From that tapGesture just notify controller that the image has been tapped.